# HTML.TextBoxFor range validation

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a TextBoxFor that I need to ensure the data provided by the user is less than a number at run time.

Current code -

```
        <div class="col-md-3 input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px; ">$</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SaveDiscountAmount, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "input-discount" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SaveDiscountAmount)
        </div>
```

I need to ensure that the discount amount entered is less than or equal to the total amount ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the validation like this if you didn't have:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
[Range(typeof(int), "0", "100",ErrorMessage = "{0} can only be between {1} and {2}")]
public int SaveDiscountAmount{get;set;}
```

or:

try this:

```
[Range(min,max)]
```

where min and max are the numbers you defined for range.

Comment: I am familiar with your answer but you missed the part about during run time.  I don't know what the max number is until the order is placed.